# Calculate number of singletons in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have some RNA-seq data and I need to calculate the number of singletons.  We define a singleton as a read that does not have any other reads mapped close by (in a distance of 100 bases to either side).

I have a dataframe with the begin coordinate and the end coordinate of each read. I'm using R to do this.

I have written this code for the moment, but the apply is not correct and therefore is giving an error.

```
begin_end <- data.frame(begin_coordinate, final_coordinate)
apply(begin_end, 1, function(x) x[,1]-(x-1)[,2])
```

The first lines of the dataframe are:

```
> head(begin_end)

    begin   final
1   60507   60551
2   60790   60840
3   62004   62051
4   62819   62868
5   65141   65187
```

The first one seems to be a singleton because the next reads starts more than 100 bases after it ends and so are the rest in the first lines of the dataset. But the dataframe is long and I hope not all the reads are singletons.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the same thing @jeremycg did with dplyr's `lag` and `lead`, but in data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(begin_end)

begin_end[{
  d = begin - shift(final, type="lag")
  pmin(d, shift(d, type="lead"), na.rm=TRUE) > 100
}]
```

---

**Comment.** The basic data.table syntax is `DT[i,j]`. `i` is for filtering the input while `j` is for modifying the output.

We used `i` above, but to examine how it works, we can toss the relevant vectors into `j`:

```
begin_end[,{
  d       = begin - shift(final, type="lag")
  d_lead  = shift(d, type="lead")
  my_pmin = pmin(d, d_lead, na.rm=TRUE)
  c(.SD, list(d = d, d_lead = d_lead, my_pmin = my_pmin))
}]

#    begin final    d d_lead my_pmin
# 1: 60507 60551   NA    239     239
# 2: 60790 60840  239   1164     239
# 3: 62004 62051 1164    768     768
# 4: 62819 62868  768   2273     768
# 5: 65141 65187 2273     NA    2273
```

`.SD` is a list of column vectors already in the table, short for Subset of Data.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be trying to get the previous end value out of the `apply` using `(x-1)`. Unfortunately, you can't do this inside the apply family.

Luckily, there is a function called `lag` (there are several, so i'll use the one from `dplyr`). This lets us `lag` a column by a given number of entries:

```
begin_end$space <- begin_end$begin - dplyr::lag(begin_end$final)
```

here's the output:

```
  begin final space
1 60507 60551    NA
2 60790 60840   239
3 62004 62051  1164
4 62819 62868   768
5 65141 65187  2273
```

Then you can try:

```
begin_end$issingle <- begin_end$space >= 100
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [Bioconductor](https://bioconductor.org)'s [GenomicRanges](http://bioconductor.org/packages/GenomicRanges) I think the idea would be to create a `GRanges()` (maybe from reading the data using `GenomicAlignments::readGAlignments()` or `makeGRangesFromDataFrame()`) from your reads, extend them in each direction using `resize()`, then use `findOverlaps()` to identify singletons as the reads that only overlap themselves. Roughly

```
library(GenomicRanges)
gr = GRanges(seqnames="chr1",
             IRanges(start=c(1000, 1150, 1500), width=100))
gr100 = resize(gr, width(gr) + 200, fix="center")
hits = findOverlaps(gr100)
gr100[tabulate(queryHits(hits), queryLength(hits)) == 1]
```

leading to

```
>     gr100[tabulate(queryHits(hits), queryLength(hits)) == 1]
GRanges object with 1 range and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames       ranges strand
         <Rle>    <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]     chr1 [1400, 1699]      *
  -------
  seqinfo: 1 sequence from an unspecified genome; no seqlengths
```

This will be fast for millions of records.